# How to create dependency injection for Azure Storage queues to process each message as it is provided

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-queues

Trying to read from an Azure Queue to which some other service writes. If I use this in startup.cs

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=*;AccountKey=*;EndpointSuffix=*");
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("*");
queue.CreateIfNotExists();
var message= queue.GetMessage();
```

I can get the message in 'message' variable, but how to inject this in startup so that my processor class gets called with the message each time there is a new message in the queue. I tried to add a singleton by,

```
services.AddSinleton<ProcessorClassInterface>(x=> {return new ProcessorClass(queue)});
```

And then calling `queue.GetMessage` after every 1 second there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by calling a function which uses multi-threading to poll the azure queues after the specified interval of time and fetch the messaged (with probably a set exponential back off time).

**Approach 1:** 
To implement this in a webapp is a bit trickier, and I had to use a hack - call a function from the constructor to get the polling started.

In startup.cs (inside the configure function), register your service,

```
app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IQueueConsumer>();
```

In ConfigureServices Function, Configuring and creating an object of the polling queue class,

```
services.TryAddTransient<IQueueConsumer>(sp => this.GetQueueProcessor(sp));
```

And then, when the constructor is called to create the object, start polling a queue in a different thread.

```
public QueuePollingFunction(
        IOptions<QueueOptions> queueOptions,
        CloudQueue queue)
    {
        this.isEnabled = queueOptions.Value.IsEnabled;
        this.StartPollingQueue(queue);
    }

       public override async Task<bool> ProcessMessageAsync(string message)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            var messageContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueueEntity>(message);
            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(e.ToString());
        }

        return result;
    }

    private async Task StartPollingQueue(CloudQueue queue)
    {
        if (this.isEnabled)
        {
            Task pollQueue = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.For(0, this.numberOfParallelTasks, work =>
            {
                this.Start(queue);
            }));
        }
    }

    private async Task Start(CloudQueue queue)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                CloudQueueMessage retrievedMessage = await queue.GetMessageAsync();
                if (retrievedMessage != null)
                {
                    // Fail Logic
                    if (retrievedMessage.DequeueCount > this.maxRetryLimit)
                    {
                        await queue.DeleteMessageAsync(retrievedMessage);
                    }
                    bool isPass = await this.ProcessMessageAsync(newChannelSettings);
                    if (isPass)
                    {
                        await queue.DeleteMessageAsync(retrievedMessage);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // If queue is empty, then the Task can sleep for sleepTime duration
                    await Task.Delay(this.sleepTime);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Trace.TraceError(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Approach 2:**
However, later had to move to the optimal approach, which is to use worker-roles and then uses Tasks to run a background thread to perform this task.